# why cast when the conversion is implicit?

Tags: c, casting

I see some code in c like this

```
int main()
{
    int x = 4, y = 6;
    long z = (long) x + y;

}
```

what is the benefit of casting even though in this case it implicit? Which operation comes first x + y or casting x first?

Comment: that use long arithmetic to avoid potentiel overflow of int arithmetic.

Answer (score 7):

In this case the cast *can* serve a purpose.  If you wrote

```
int x = 4, y = 6;
long z = x + y;
```

the addition would be performed on `int` values, and then, afterwards, the sum would be converted to `long`.  So the addition might overflow.  In this case, casting one operand causes the addition to be performed using `long` values, lessening the chance of overflow.

(Obviously in the case of `4` and `6` it's not going to overflow anyway.)

In answer to your second question, when you write

```
long z = (long)x + y;
```

the cast is definitely applied first, and that's important.  If, on the other hand, you wrote

```
long z = (long)(x + y);
```

the cast would be applied after the addition (and it would be too late, because the addition would have already been performed on ints).

Similarly, if you write

```
float f = x / y;
```

or even

```
float f = (float)(x / y);
```

the division will be performed on `int` values, and will discard the remainder, and `f` will end up containing 0.  But if you write

```
float f = (float)x / y;
```

the division will be performed using floating-point, and `f` will receive 0.666666.

Comment: Not always - the promotion rules are more complicated https://ideone.com/1Ofxgj  But it is of course safer to cast.